# How to compile AIR iOS apps inlcuding ANE from the command line?

Tags: command-line, air, ane

I'm new to compiling AIR iOS apps with the command line. My current command looks like this:

```
./adt -package -target ipa-app-store -storetype pkcs12 -keystore iOS7.p12 -provisioning-profile Africa_DragDrop_iPad.mobileprovision Africa_iPad.ipa Africa_iPad-app.xml Africa_iPad.swf AfricaIcon29.png AfricaIcon40.png AfricaIcon48.png AfricaIcon50.png AfricaIcon57.png AfricaIcon58.png AfricaIcon72.png AfricaIcon76.png AfricaIcon80.png AfricaIcon100.png AfricaIcon114.png AfricaIcon120.png AfricaIcon128.png AfricaIcon144.png AfricaIcon152.png AfricaIcon512.png AfricaIcon1024.png Default-Landscape.png
```

What is the correct way to add an `.ane` (AIR Native Extension) to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the extension directory to your options:

```
adt -package
    -target ipa-app-store
    -provisioning-profile Africa_DragDrop_iPad.mobileprovision
    -storetype pkcs12
    -keystore iOS7.p12
    Africa_iPad.ipa Africa_iPad-app.xml Africa_iPad.swf AfricaIcon29.png AfricaIcon40.png AfricaIcon48.png AfricaIcon50.png AfricaIcon57.png AfricaIcon58.png AfricaIcon72.png AfricaIcon76.png AfricaIcon80.png AfricaIcon100.png AfricaIcon114.png AfricaIcon120.png AfricaIcon128.png AfricaIcon144.png AfricaIcon152.png AfricaIcon512.png AfricaIcon1024.png Default-Landscape.png
    -extdir DIRECTORY_CONTAINING_ANES
```

And also, make sure that you have specified the extensions in the application descriptor  node.

More information on the adt directories here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128fc240122-7ff2.html

Comment: Is it only the directory or do I need to add the ANE names to the options too? e.g.; `aneFileName1.ane aneFileName2.ane -extdir extensions`

Comment: Just the directory containing all the ANE files. The only other thing you need to do is include them in that extensions node of your application descriptor.

Comment: Thank you very much! I like your AIR extensions btw - keep up the good work

Comment: Cheers! And will do :)